# How to implement a Contract-First

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, wsdl, contract-first

I am doing some work with a 3rd party supplier who provide data via a web-push.

They state that their web-push relies on a contract-first web service, and they have made a WSDL available for me to develop with.

What are the steps involved in taking this WSDL and turning it into a webservice? I have had one go at it, but my service does not register any data hitting it.

I realise this is a bit vague, but this whole "contract-first" is quite new to me.

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: `svcutil.exe` probably accepts a WDSL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract first is a great approach but unfortunately the tooling from Microsoft isn't great for this approach. WCF does a good job at hiding what the actual WSDL file looks like from developers.

Have a look at svcutil.exe to generate your client proxy classes from the contract (WSDL) you can specify the path to wsdl and the code language to generate As arguments to the tool .otherwise check out the tool from  called  wcf blue tool

Happy coding & you'll get the hang of WSDL pretty quickly !